# How to run E2E tests in Nest.JS

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I am now making a NestJS app and in the common boilerplate it has the src and test folders, src has the source code, each folder inside it is a module, and each module has tests for the controllers and services inside it.

But the test folder that is outside `src` folder is used only for e2e tests, but when I run `yarn test` in the root directory, it only runs tests from the `src` directory.

How can I run the e2e tests?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the following script on your terminal:

```
npm run test:e2e
```

Make sure that the script is defined in your package.json like this:

```
jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json
```

Answer (score 0):

So create a `jest.config.js` in the root of module and use `testMatch` property which accept an array and then you can define the files which end with spec.ts then run them.

```
// jest.config.js
{
   testMatch: ['**/*.spec.ts'],
   testEnvironment: 'node',
  ...
}
```

By using this property, it will run tests outside the `src` folder.

Comment: if you generated the nestjs app you should be able to run the unit tests with yarn test and the e2e tests with yarn test:e2e, check the package.json

Comment: If npm use 'npm run test:e2e'.

Answer (score 0):

To Run E2E test file you need to run below code in terminal as given below:

```
npm run test:e2e
```